# Mach-O Librarian error while adding OAuthSwift cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, xcode6, cocoapods

I'm trying to build an xcode project developing in swift using the OAuthSwift Cocoapod.  I'm getting an error with the compiler is creating a static library.  Error posted below..

```
Libtool /Users/Josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Whistle-gvivrqpbrrykshduohmpjjdibxka/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-OAuthSwift.a normal x86_64
cd "/Users/Josh/Desktop/MOB 01/whistle/whistle/Pods"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/Josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Whistle-gvivrqpbrrykshduohmpjjdibxka/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Whistle-gvivrqpbrrykshduohmpjjdibxka/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-OAuthSwift.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pods-OAuthSwift.LinkFileList -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Whistle-gvivrqpbrrykshduohmpjjdibxka/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-`OAuthSwift`.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pods_OAuthSwift.swiftmodule -framework Foundation -o /Users/Josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Whistle-gvivrqpbrrykshduohmpjjdibxka/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-OAuthSwift.a

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-sacLT] [-no_warning_for_no_symbols]
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -dynamic [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-o output] [-install_name name] [-compatibility_version #] [-current_version #] [-seg1addr 0x#] [-segs_read_only_addr 0x#] [-segs_read_write_addr 0x#] [-seg_addr_table <filename>] [-seg_addr_table_filename <file_system_path>] [-all_load] [-noall_load]
```

Any Suggestions??

UPDATE: Podfile below

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'LayerKit'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'OAuthSwift'
```

Comment: Post your podfile please

Comment: Added the podfile to the question

Comment: Look at oauthswift's read me file on installation with pods, it says platform ios 7 and he selects a version of oauthswift. https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift/blob/master/README.md